# Django CMS - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I am trying to install djangoCMS on my Ubuntu 15.04.
First I had a "pillow not compiled with jpeg" issue, but managed to solve it by installing another pip version (pip install Pillow==2.3) before running `djangocms -f -p . myproject.`

```
Running migrations:
      Rendering model states...Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/folder/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/folder/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
        self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
      File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/folder/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 393, in run_from_argv
        self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
      File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/folder/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 444, in execute
        output = self.handle(*args, **options)
      File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/folder/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 221, in handle
        executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
      File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/folder/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 104, in migrate
        state = migration.mutate_state(state, preserve=do_run)
      File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/folder/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 83, in mutate_state
        operation.state_forwards(self.app_label, new_state)
      File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/folder/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 53, in state_forwards
        list(self.managers),
      File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/folder/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 81, in add_model
        self.reload_model(app_label, model_name)
      File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/folder/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 122, in reload_model
        related_models.update(get_related_models_recursive(rel_model))
      File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/folder/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 57, in get_related_models_recursive
        rel_app_label, rel_model_name = rel_mod._meta.app_label, rel_mod._meta.model_name
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Can anyone explain to me why? And how to solve it?
Thank you!

**UPDATE:**

I installed django CMS inside the virtualenv like this:

```
pip install djangocms-installer
```

pip freeze:

```
cmsplugin-filer==0.10.1
dj-database-url==0.3.0
Django==1.8.3
django-appconf==1.0.1
django-classy-tags==0.6.2
django-cms==3.1.2
django-filer==0.9.11
django-mptt==0.7.4
django-polymorphic==0.7.1
django-reversion==1.8.5
django-sekizai==0.8.2
Django-Select2==4.3.1
django-treebeard==3.0
djangocms-admin-style==0.2.7
djangocms-column==1.5
djangocms-flash==0.2.0
djangocms-googlemap==0.2
djangocms-inherit==0.1
djangocms-installer==0.7.8
djangocms-link==1.6.2
djangocms-style==1.5
djangocms-text-ckeditor==2.5.2
easy-thumbnails==2.2
html5lib==0.999999
Pillow==2.3.0
pytz==2015.4
six==1.9.0
tzlocal==1.2
Unidecode==0.4.18
wheel==0.24.0
```

Comment: seems one of your models has a relation to another model that doesn't exist, check your migrations

Comment: What command did you use to install Django CMS, itself? And what's the output of `pip freeze`?

Comment: Thank you for answering! I have updated the post.. I don't understand how one of the models has a relation to another model that doesn't exist, when this is supposed to be a first clean install of django-cms?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is solved in support/3.1.x branch of django-cms.
You can checkout it or wait the next release : 3.1.3 tag.

Comment: How can I implement the support/3.1.x branch of django-cms, when I am running my project on Aldryne?

Comment: Can you link to the commit in question?

Comment: Troyer : If you can run pip, you can use git repo instead of pip packages. for ex : pip install git+https://github.com/divio/django-cms.git@support/3.1.x

Janus : I didn't find the specific commit because of I didn't know what exactly was causing this (this was around the CMSPlugin model). I'm currently running many installations and tests on our "DjangoBootstrap" project and upgrading to 3.1.x branch solved the problem.